# .Net migration The entity type 'List<int>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, migration

Hello guys I have a problem with migraiton.I use abstract class like:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Then I have 2 tables like as follows:

```
public class MovieFavoriteList:FavoriteListBase<int>
    {
        public List<int> MovieIds { get; set; }

    }
public class TvSeriesFavoriteList:FavoriteListBase<int>
    {
        
        public List<int> TvIds { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to migrate this error occurs:

> The entity type 'List<int>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

Do you guys have an idea about how can I fix it ?

I try as follows:

```
 [Keyless]
    public class TvSeriesFavoriteList:FavoriteListBase<int>
    {
        
        public List<int> TvIds { get; set; }
    }
```

however then I realized it was nonsense:

Comment: Int32 is not an entity. Do you want to create one to many relationship? If so, this is not how you should do this in EF Core...

Comment: I want to store multiple movieids within a favori list.Therefore I dont figure it out how can I create model ? property like list of movieids.

Comment: You should create many to many relationship and create list od movies, not their ids. Read more here: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key. If you are using .net6 or .net7 you also dont have to craete seperate model with connections between users and movies unless you want to store some addtional information between those connections (for example date of creation). And ofc movie must have its Id.

Answer (score -1):

### It gives this error because the primary key cannot be found.
If you want to use the default convention, use this attribute for the attributes you want to make primary key.

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(MovieIds)]
public int MovieIds {get;set;}
```

### OR For Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Entity<MovieFavoriteList>().HasKey(p=>p.MovieIds)
}
```